# How do I avoid infinite circular references when mapping ebean to json with jackson?

Tags: java, json, playframework-2.0, ebean

I'm currently using Play! 2.0.4 with Ebean and Jackson. I have a OneToMany relationship between User and Contact. I'm using Jacksons ObjectMapper to convert objects to json, but I'm running into issues with circular references during the conversion.

```
class User extends Model {
    List<Contact> contacts;
}

class Contact extends Model {
    User user;
}
```

I want to fetch a list of all Contacts, and convert this list to json, including the foreign key linking it to Users, but do not need any data from the User table itself.

At the moment I'm getting StackOverflowError when using ObjectMapper to create this list. I understand why, but not sure how to best solve it.

I've omitted any annotations and code I think isn't relevant, but let me know if more code is needed.

Comment: This might not help, but I've always been under the impression that a circular reference means your design is flawed. 

Is there a reason as to why you are required to have the User contained within the Contact?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used the Play framework, but JPA lets you map a OneToMany or ManyToMany relationship from one entity to another. Then in the 2nd entity it reads across that same relationship backwards, so there's only one relationship. Your issue sounds like you have 2 relationships, one going each way.

Look for the Play eBean equivalent of @OneToMany(mappedBy="user") for the contacts member in your User class.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to fetch a List o results, iterate it and create new List containing only required data. I'm not sure about ObjectMapper, however I had [similar problem](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/play-framework/json%2420biesior/play-framework/xVDmm4hQqfY/5tojzgRWCggJ) and it seems that toJson() method forced building whole objects with all relations.

Since that question I built some JSON APIs and remembering that experience I decided to manually build new object for each row. Some of my APIs can (should) return large datasets, so it was important to me to select data carefully, without redundant (not used) fields etc. ie. like this

```
public static Result jsonAll(){

    // initiate empty result List
    List results = new ArrayList();

    List<Marker> tasks = Marker.find.select("id, name").findList();
    for (Marker task : tasks) {

        // build 'item'
        Map<String, Object> item = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        item.put("id", task.id);
        item.put("name", task.name);

        // add the 'item' to 'results'
        results.add(item);

    }

    // return all as JSON
    return ok(Json.toJson(results));
}
```

Of course you need to fetch relations so you need to add [`fetch()` statement](http://www.avaje.org/ebean/introquery_join.html) to the finder and point exact relations and fields to choose.